# how to get my band frequency in android with java

Tags: java, android, frequency, gsm

i'm working on a apk where i want to get the band frequency of my network, for example if my telephone is gsm i want to know if is on 850 band.

I was reading in android develop but i cant find anything. Also, i was reading the android.telephony library, but i dont know if that library can help me.

For now im only obtain cell id and lac.

```
      TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
      GsmCellLocation cellLocation = (GsmCellLocation)telephonyManager.getCellLocation();

      int cid = cellLocation.getCid();
      int lac = cellLocation.getLac();
      textGsmCellLocation.setText(cellLocation.toString());
      textCID.setText("gsm cell id: " + String.valueOf(cid));
      textLAC.setText("gsm location area code: " + String.valueOf(lac));
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Times before, I've worked in a project where we needed to get the same types of information (low-level, network-context info). After a great amount of researches, I think that you can't retrieve these types of info with Android's default API. Maybe you can try something with reflection (I believe that Qualipoc uses things like it) or, re-implement/customize the Android-RIL.